# Bootstrap inline form elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to place a CAPTCHA image and text box inline. I tried grouping solutions, inline solutions and many others. However, it not helping me.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screen shot for reference]

```
<form action="/Default/Perform" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="txtPassword">Password</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         <input type="password" class="form-control" id="txtPassword" maxlength="10" size="10" placeholder="Enter a password">
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">                        
     <label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="CaptchaText">Enter the number:</label>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
         <img src="/Default/ShowCaptchaImage">&nbsp;<input class="form-control" id="CaptchaText" name="CaptchaText" type="text">
     </div>
</div> 
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post some of your CSS?

Comment: any specific css required? I am using default bootstrap css styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one class and give css like:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 test">
   <img src="/Default/ShowCaptchaImage">&nbsp;
   <input class="form-control" id="CaptchaText" name="CaptchaText" type="text">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test{
  display:flex;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eg9vgeq3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change as follows

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
     <img src="/Default/ShowCaptchaImage" style="float:left;">&nbsp;<input class="form-control" id="CaptchaText" style="float:left;" name="CaptchaText" type="text">
 </div>
```